# Android split string with regex not working

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to split a string at every "." or "?" and I use this regular expression:

```
(?<=(?!.[0-9])[?.])
```

In theory the code also prevents splitting if the point is followed by a number so things like 3.000 are not split and it also includes the point in the new string.

For example if I have this text: "Hello. What's your favourite number? It's 3.560." I want to get thi: "Hello.","What's your favourite number?","It's 3.560."

I've made a simple java program on my computer and it works exactly like I want:

```
String[] x = c.split("(?<=(?!.[0-9])[?.])");
for(String v : x){
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

However when I use this same regex in my Android app it doesn't split anything...

```
x = txt.split("(?<=(?!.[0-9])[?.])");
//This, in my android app, returns an array with only one entry which is the whole string without splitting.
```

PS. Using (?<=[?.]) works so the problem must be in the (?!.[0-9]) part which is meant to exclude points followed by a number.

Comment: In the app the user enters the string but I've been trying with the text in this article: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-57550564-251/samsung-galaxy-s3-to-get-multiview-smart-rotation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?:(?<=[.])(?![0-9])|(?<=[?]))
```

---

```
str.split("(?:(?<=[.])(?![0-9])|(?<=[?]))");
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks this one does work! Can you tell me why mine didn't work?

Comment: @JouiCK - (1) there should not be a period in your negative lookahead; (2) should not apply negative lookahead for `?`; (3) should have lookahead out of lookbehind (recommended)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that outside a square bracket character class, `.` in a regular expression means *any* single character. You need `\.` to match a literal dot, which in turn means you need `\\.` in the string literal.

Comment: like this? (?<=(?!\\.[0-9])[?\\.])

Comment: it doesn't work either on Android but it does in the java program, on my computer.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking you don't need the \\ inside the `[?.]` but I don't think it does any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String regex = "[?.][^\\d]";
        String tester = "Testing 3.015 dsd . sd ? sds";
        String[] arr = tester.split(regex);
        for (String s : arr){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Testing 3.015 dsd 
sd 
sds
```

Comment: This one seems to work but it doesn't return the "." at the end like Omega's one. Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: The one at the end is easily appendable.